# Oracle Data Provider for .NET, custom data types

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I am using Entity Framework and Oracle Data Provider for .NET as connector.

I have an EDMX model where there is a property which type is Enum.

When I try to generate database from model I get this error:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Namespace.EnumType

I can't change Enum to other type.

What can I do to avoid this error?